# How to install spyder-unittest on Spyder IDE

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I do `conda install -c spyder-ide spyder-unittest` according to https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-unittest, but I keep getting

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: ...
```

What do I do wrong? Sorry, it seems simple, but I just started using Anaconda and Spyder.

Comment: What happens next - does the install command eventually fail? conda can take a long time to finish an `install` or `create` operation if there are many dependencies to resolve. I assume you're trying to install into the base environment?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder-unittest is incompatible with Spyder 5, so that's (most probably) why you're unable to install it. We're working to fix that at the moment and hopefully a new version will be available in the next months.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer!!! Acutally it seemed like the installation went through, it just took more than two hours, which was already suspicious. I was just a little impatient. The second answer explains, why it still does not work :). Is there a reasonable alternative for unittesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment above, spyder-unittest is incompatible with Spyder 5 at the moment. Solution: `conda uninstall spyder` and `conda install spyder=4.2.5`. Just downgrading with `conda install spyder=4.2.5` DID NOT WORK. After that `conda install -c spyder-ide spyder-unittest` worked like a charm in no time and the expected buttons are shown in the IDE.